# How to call an operator with constexpr without using temporary variables?

Tags: c++, constants, c++20

The following sample code illustrates my problem.

```
constexpr int fact(int N) {
    return N ? N * fact(N - 1) : 1;
}
struct A {
    int d;
    constexpr A operator+(const A& other) const { return A{ fact(d + other.d) }; }
    // overload of many other operators
};

int main() {
    int x;
    cin >> x;                       // run time argument

    constexpr A a{ 2 }, b{ 3 };
    A c{ x };

    A u = a + b + c;                // both + eval at run time
    //constexpr A v = a + b + c;    // doesn't compile because c is not constant
}
```

What I want to achieve is that the first `operator+` is evaluated at compile time and the second `operator+` is evaluated at run time.

It is of course possible to break it into

```
constexpr A tmp = a + b;
A u = tmp + c;
```

but in my case the whole point of overloading operators is to allow building more complicated formulas in a more intuitive way, so that would make the overloading pointless.

If I declare `operator+` as `consteval`, then it again doesn't compile. And I cannot overload it twice.

Is there a solution?

Comment: it's evaluate at compile time https://godbolt.org/z/7PYY1cjnv if you enable optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the evaluation with (non-type) template parameter or `consteval` function.

```cpp
constexpr int fact(int N) {
    return N ? N * fact(N - 1) : 1;
}
struct A {
    int d;
    constexpr A operator+(const A& other) const { return A{ fact(d + other.d) }; }
};

consteval auto value(auto v){return v;}

A foo (int x) {

    constexpr A a{ 2 }, b{ 3 };
    A c{ x };

    A u = value(a+b) + c;
    return u;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ohf61vebv

Answer (score 0):

No, at least in gcc and with optimization, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/7PYY1cjnv) you can see it evaluate at compile time. (the `120`)

```
main:
        mov     eax, 1
        add     edi, 120
        je      .L4
.L3:
        imul    eax, edi
        sub     edi, 1
        jne     .L3
        ret
.L4:
        ret
```

*To be fair even without `constexpr` compiler would probably also optimize it.

Comment: This however is the decision of the compiler, which is not guaranteed by the language. On VS2019 release build my disassembly code shows that both are evaluated at run time. I would like to know whether it is possible to achieve the same effect as breaking it into `constexpr A tmp = a + b;
A u = tmp + c;` without depending on the compiler.

Comment: @WhatsUp afaict even if you write it that way compiler is not *required* to evaluate that at compile time (mscv execute that at compile time though)

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's not forced. But at least I do my best to tell the compiler to do so ...